# Opening multi line Json on pandas results on keys not being seperated in the columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to open in pandas a json file from this file

https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/dev-v2.0.json

however, the resulting data frame results in each line containing the whole json line, instead of separating out the columns.

Here is my code.

import urllib.request

```
url = 'https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/dev-v2.0.json'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'dev.json')

import pandas as pd
import json

pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 800)

data_df = pd.read_json('dev.json')

data_df.head()

    version data
0   v2.0    {'title': 'Normans', 'paragraphs': [{'qas': [{'question': 'In what country is Normandy located?', 'id': '56ddde6b9a695914005b9628', 'answers': [{'text': 'France', 'answer_start': 159}, {'text': 'France', 'answer_start': 159}, {'text': 'France', 'answer_start': 159}, {'text': 'France', 'answer_start': 159}], 'is_impossible': False}, {'question': 'When were the Normans in Normandy?', 'id': '56ddde6b9a695914005b9629', 'answers': [{'text': '10th and 11th centuries', 'answer_start': 94}, {'text': 'in the 10th and 11th centuries', 'answer_start': 87}, {'text': '10th and 11th centuries', 'answer_start': 94}, {'text': '10th and 11th centuries', 'answer_start': 94}], 'is_impossible': False}, {'question': 'From which countries did the Norse originate?', 'id': '56ddde6b9a695914005b962a', 'answers...
1   v2.0    {'title': 'Computational_complexity_theory', 'paragraphs': [{'qas': [{'question': 'What branch of theoretical computer science deals with broadly classifying computational problems by difficulty and class of relationship?', 'id': '56e16182e3433e1400422e28', 'answers': [{'text': 'Computational complexity theory', 'answer_start': 0}, {'text': 'Computational complexity theory', 'answer_start': 0}, {'text': 'Computational complexity theory', 'answer_start': 0}], 'is_impossible': False}, {'question': 'By what main attribute are computational problems classified utilizing computational complexity theory? ', 'id': '56e16182e3433e1400422e29', 'answers': [{'text': 'inherent difficulty', 'answer_start': 175}, {'text': 'their inherent difficulty', 'answer_start': 169}, {'text': 'inherent difficul...
2   v2.0    {'title': 'Southern_California', 'paragraphs': [{'qas': [{'question': 'What is Southern California often abbreviated as?', 'id': '5705e26d75f01819005e76d4', 'answers': [{'text': 'SoCal', 'answer_start': 39}, {'text': 'SoCal', 'answer_start': 39}, {'text': 'SoCal', 'answer_start': 39}], 'is_impossible': False}, {'question': 'Despite being traditionall described as "eight counties", how many counties does this region actually have?', 'id': '5705e26d75f01819005e76d5', 'answers': [{'text': '10 counties', 'answer_start': 133}, {'text': '10', 'answer_start': 133}, {'text': '10', 'answer_start': 133}], 'is_impossible': False}, {'question': 'What is a major importance of Southern California in relation to California and the United States?', 'id': '5705e26d75f01819005e76d6', 'answers': [{'text'...
3   v2.0    {'title': 'Sky_(United_Kingdom)', 'paragraphs': [{'qas': [{'question': 'What company was formed by the merger of Sky Television and British Satellite Broadcasting?', 'id': '57092322efce8f15003a7db0', 'answers': [{'text': 'BSkyB', 'answer_start': 98}, {'text': 'BSkyB', 'answer_start': 98}, {'text': 'BSkyB', 'answer_start': 98}], 'is_impossible': False}, {'question': "Who is the UK's largest digital subscription television company?", 'id': '57092322efce8f15003a7db1', 'answers': [{'text': 'BSkyB', 'answer_start': 98}, {'text': 'BSkyB', 'answer_start': 98}, {'text': 'BSkyB', 'answer_start': 98}], 'is_impossible': False}, {'question': 'What year did BSkyB acquire Sky Italia?', 'id': '57092322efce8f15003a7db2', 'answers': [{'text': '2014', 'answer_start': 187}, {'text': '2014', 'answer_start...
4   v2.0    {'title': 'Victoria_(Australia)', 'paragraphs': [{'qas': [{'question': 'What kind of economy does Victoria have?', 'id': '570d2417fed7b91900d45c3d', 'answers': [{'text': 'diversified', 'answer_start': 34}, {'text': 'highly diversified', 'answer_start': 27}, {'text': 'highly diversified', 'answer_start': 27}], 'is_impossible': False}, {'question': 'Where according to gross state product does Victoria rank in Australia?', 'id': '570d2417fed7b91900d45c3e', 'answers': [{'text': 'second', 'answer_start': 266}, {'text': 'second', 'answer_start': 266}, {'text': 'second', 'answer_start': 266}], 'is_impossible': False}, {'question': 'At what rank does GPS per capita set Victoria?', 'id': '570d2417fed7b91900d45c3f', 'answers': [{'text': 'fourth', 'answer_start': 315}, {'text': 'fourth', 'answer_...
```

For convenience, here's a link to the colab notebook so people don't have to download the data directly

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19apJGZsrlFI3XCp8OmHbEhbHkJEjp0T5

I tried `data_df1 = pd.read_json('dev.json', lines=True)` that that just puts all the lines into one row

Comment: That's tough, your JSON is deeply nested. Use `json_normalize` instead.

Comment: I tried json_normalize(data) , but that gave a pd dataframe of just one row

Comment: You will need to play around with the `record_path` and `meta` arguments. Check out the docs:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html